# Buffering program output when the program author doesn't do it in the first place

Tags: linux

I have a program which I suspect is coded incorrectly. I think it doesn't do buffering but instead write to disk line by line. The way I specify file name is -e . The question is is there something I can try to make it write to RAM and move it to disk upon application completion?

Actually I would like something like /dev/null but something from where I can collect the output

Comment: If the application is not buffering itself the problem may be high CPU usage (imho of type "system") because of high rate of system calls. This would be hard to solve without modifying the application.

Comment: The thing is. I don't know how the app works. I can only guess. The thing is when it produces same output in binary format it does it many times faster than when writing text output. The problem is other apps fail to read this binary output. So assuming that what the app actually does the same stuff regardless of outputting ASCII or binary, I thought the only thing might be broken buffering (because I seen it before).

Answer (score 0):

A bit of a workaround that might improve performance - you could you create a ramdisk and have it send it's output to that. There's lots of howtos online, but here's one:

http://www.vanemery.com/Linux/Ramdisk/ramdisk.html

Comment: I suspect this requires root rights?

Answer (score 0):

Most filesystems will buffer writes anyway unless the application specifically requests synchronous behaviour. For example, the ext2 filesystem will wait up to 30 seconds before flushing writes to disk. So, even poor code like you suspect should not cause significant performance degradation.

You could try using the `async` mount option to change the behaviour of the filesystem:

```
async  All I/O to the filesystem should be done asynchronously.
```

Another approach could be to redirect the output using a [named pipe](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/using-named-pipes-fifos-bash). That would give you all the flexibility in the world to buffer the output in memory.